# Getting ValidationException on UpdateTableCommand (AWS SDK)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to the update the deletion protection setting for my DynamoDB table:

```
this.#docClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: REGION });
...
updateParams = {
  TableName: TABLE_NAME,
  DeletionProtectionEnabled: true
}
let updateResponse = await this.#docClient.send(new UpdateTableCommand(updateParams));
```

But I'm running into this error:

```
ValidationException: At least one of ProvisionedThroughput, BillingMode, UpdateStreamEnabled, GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates, SSESpecification, ReplicaUpdates, DeletionProtectionEnabled or TableClass is required
    at deserializeAws_json1_0UpdateTableCommandError (/Users/matthewguo/Desktop/pdc/pdc-console/server/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist/cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:4092:41)
...
```

However I clearly do pass in DeletionProtectionEnabled, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by upgrading the @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb package from 3.0.0 to the latest (3.405.0).